# Android - Dialog onResume?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have an action that takes place in `Dialog`. That action starts another app which results I get in `onActivityResult` in the `Activity`. Now, I want special "something" to happen when the results are received, but in the `Dialog`. Is there something like `onResume` or `onActivityResult` but for dialogs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can create an Activity and give it a Dialog theme. It'll work just like an Activity, but look like a dialog.

Just add this

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

If you don't want to go this route you can also use Message Handlers.
That way you can pump message to where ever from where ever.

This is a decent post.
http://idlesun.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/android-handler-and-message-tutorial/

Comment: so as I understand you suggest passing a Handler from the Activity to the Dialog, and then whenever new data is in the Activity, just post it to the Dialog? Right?

Comment: Yes. Your can just call mDataHandler.sendMessage(Message) in your Activity and then process that in the Dialog.

Comment: ok, and how about the first idea you put, making the Activity actually a Dialog? Isn't that bad design? I think it will solve my problem, but the thing is I want to distribute this project as library and I want to wrap everything in the Dialog.

Comment: Well if your trying to make a lib then this may not be the cleanest solution. You can set the theme in java, but your users are going to have to put your Activity in their manifest file in order to resolve an intent to you. Having problems with handlers...? Hehe. I suppose you can also expose and interface and use that. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your `Dialog` in an `Activity`, create a variable to house your `Dialog`, then in `onCreate()` for the `Activity`, build the actual `Dialog` and `show()` it. When the `Activity` receives the results, it could reference the `Dialog` by the variable name and call any necessary methods.

Comment: but I am doing it as separate library so I need only the dialog :/